# How to know date and time of Java EE server start?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I need to know in Servlet or Filter the date and time (in any format) of last Java EE application server's start.

How to do that in the most compatible way?

Answer (score 4):

To get the millisecond since start up, try this:

```
long jvmUpTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime();
```

or:

```
long jvmStartTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime();
```

Then convert it to any format you want, i.e

```
Date date = new Date(jvmUpTime);
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getInstance();
String formattedDate = df.format(date);
```

The `RuntimeMXBean` requires java 5. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html